# Securing sensitive information in onsenUI/Angular

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui, angular-fullstack

I am creating an app using monaca/onsenUI front-end with a firebase backend. In the front end, I have a script that makes the connection to my firebase

```
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "myApiKey",
    authDomain: "onsenapp.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://onsenapp.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

I am wondering how to secure the API key so users won't have API key when they look at the source code. In Rails, I believe you store the sensitive data in a .yml file and save the sensitive information in environment variables.  What do you do in this case to protect sensitive data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, why should users be able to see the code? Are you using Onsen to develop a web-app?

If you are developing a Cordova App, you can use Monaca Power Plugins, like [HTML5 Resource Encryption](https://docs.monaca.io/en/reference/power_plugins/html5_resource_encryption/) in order to encrypt your source code.

Comment: Wow. You are completely correct. This is my first hybrid app (I have only built web apps), and I forgot that users cannot access the code. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First thing to make it safe would be not to post it online for the whole world to see.

Other than that, you can't really hide this data, it's how firebase works. You have option to set [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/), which is a step towards protecting the data, but not the full solution. If the plan is to store sensitive data, I wouldn't pick firebase in the first place.

Comment: Thanks.  As for the key in my post, it's just a fake key and url I made up for the purpose of this question. Thanks for the link.